# Is there a Google Chrome version 50 supporting Mac OS 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, upgrade, google-chrome

My Chrome 49 stopped receiving updates following [Google's announcement of discontinuing support for Mac OS 10.8](https://chrome.googleblog.com/2015/11/updates-to-chrome-platform-support.html).

Is there any way to install any Chrome version 50 supporting Mac OS 10.8.5 manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the present time the latest version of Google Chrome is: 50.0.2661.94

- Under OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5...

If you do not have Google Chrome installed, and you download a copy and install it, the version will show as: 49.0.2623.112

If you then try to update it through Google Chrome it will report: "Google Chrome is up to date."

- Note that the downloaded *googlechrome.dmg* file's URL is:

https://dl.google.com/dl/chrome/mac/legacy/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg

If you have an earlier version installed, e.g. 48.0.2564.109, and update it through Google Chrome it will report: "Google Chrome is up to date."

- On later versions of OS X, the downloaded *googlechrome.dmg* file's URL is:

https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/CHFA/googlechrome.dmg

- At the present time that *googlechrome.dmg* file contains version: 50.0.2661.94

To get the latest version of Google Chrome on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.x, do the following:

1. Download the *googlechrome.dmg* file from the link directly above,
   not the one that has "legacy" in its URL.
2. If open, close Google Chrome and delete it from the Applications
   folder.
3. Open the newly downloaded *googlechrome.dmg* file and in spite of
   the international no symbol showing, drag and drop it into the
   Applications folder, not the Applications link in the installer
   *.dmg* file.
4. Open Terminal and use the following command to modify the
   *Info.plist* file inside the Google Chrome application bundle:

   ```
   defaults write /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist LSMinimumSystemVersion 10.8.0
   ```

Note: Copy and paste the entire command above into the Terminal and then press Enter.

5. Now select the Google Chrome application bundle in the Applications
   folder and press 
   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to open its Get
   Info sheet and then close the Get Info sheet.
6. In a Terminal run the following command: `killall Finder`

The Google Chrome application icon should now show as normal.

Now you can run the latest Google Chrome on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.x.

- **Note:** While the current latest version of Google Chrome (50.0.2661.94) is running fine for me under OS X Mountain Lion
  10.8.5, this does't mean that future versions will run without issue on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5, and therefore this method will become
  worthless.

Answer (score 4):

As the current version of Chrome is now well beyond 50, the solution in the accepted answer no longer works.

*(I tried on Mountain Lion; I was able to make the "no" symbol go away, but when I attempted to open Chrome, I simply got an error alert claiming that the app was corrupt and suggesting that I move it to the trash.)*

As the OP mentions, Chrome 50 was the first version to drop legacy OS support, so **Chrome 49 is the latest version that can be installed without much ado**. (Chrome 52 did *not* work for me as Kay Yin suggested, though your mileage may vary.)

Although the OP asks for Chrome 50, my suggestion is to **stick with Chrome 49**.

*(And since this page is a highly ranked google search result for downloading old versions of chrome, mountain lion, etc, many of those currently reading this are likely in the same situation I was in: simply looking to install a functioning Chrome on Mountain Lion.)*

Fortunately, as of today, Chrome 49 can simply be downloaded and installed from either of the following sites:

- https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php
- http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old

No other steps were necessary for me. I simply obtained Chrome 49, moved it to Applications, and then I was able to open and run it without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 52 is the last version of Chrome compatible with OS X Mountain Lion. It can be modified to run as patrix and user3439894 described in their answers.

However, the same modification will cause Chrome 53 Beta to crash upon loading pages, and Chrome 54 Canary will simply refuse to run.

[image]